# Between-subjects, factorial, crossed, cross-classified: all the same thing?

Tags: r, regression, anova, mixed-model, lme4-nlme

Suppose I have a test with $j$ items taken by $i$ persons. I wish to obtain the mean item score (`y`) taking into account that both items and persons are a sample of what I expect. As such, I take both as having random-effects.

I know persons and items, as random-effects, are crossed with one another. I also wish to know if `item_type` has any effect on the mean item score. Thus, if I'm an `R` user, I would probably use (suppose `y` is normally distributed):

```
library(lme4)
lmer(y ~ item_type + (1|persons_id) + (1|items_id), data = data) ## DON'T RUN
```

> **Question:** Which of the following terminologies applies to the design described above: $(1)$ `Between-subjects`, $(2)$ `factorial`, $(3)$ `crossed`, $(4)$ `cross-classified`?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few points to note:

- y does not need to be normally distributed for an LMM. It is the conditional distribution (ie the residuals) that should be approximately normal, in order for certain inferences to be made.
- crossed and cross-classified are the same.
- a factorial design looks very much like a crossed design. For example where each level of two or more factors is applied to the subject; hpwver not the context - we usually say that the factor was "applied" to a subject: in factorial designs the factors are often variables that are controlled by the experimenter and so are naturally thought of as fixed effects, and there are usually few levels of the factors involved, whereas in crossed designs where the factors are random we often think of them as "belonging" to the factor. Of course this is not universal. As in crossed designs, factorial designs can be incomplete - that is not all combinations of the factor levels are applied - this happens with incomplete lock designs and split block designs. With crossed models we say "partially crossed" (or equaivalantly "partially nested")
- Between-subjects is a term I don't like much and don't use often at all. Basically it just refers to a variable which only varies *between* subjects - that is, it does not vary within subjects. Sex assigned at birth would be an exmaple. Sometimes a variable can be both in different contexts - Age is often a between subjects variable in a cross-sectional study, but can be a within variable foor a longitudinal study. Note here that it is not necessary for the variable to be a factor in order for it to be "between" or "within" subjects.

Comment: Hi Robert, thanks! But so, regarding cross-classified, if you look at articles like [THIS ONE](https://www-tandfonline-com.srv-proxy1.library.tamu.edu/doi/full/10.1080/00273170902794214) or **p. 163** of [THIS BOOK](https://www.amazon.com/Multilevel-Analysis-Applications-Quantitative-Methodology/dp/1138121401), it seems to me they have one additional element at least in their notations. For example, they say pupil $i$ is nested within the `cross-classification` of primary school $j$ and secondary school $k$. In my scenario above, what is $i$, what is $j$, and what is $k$?

Comment: I don't have access to those books online and I can't see what the first one is. I have read Hox`, it is a classic "multilevel modelling" text, but I don't recall what you are referring to exactly. It seems they just have pupils nested in primary schools, and secondary schools. Since pupils cannot be in both at the same time it is not multiple membership; primary schools don't *belong* to a secondary school (or vice versa) so it must be a crossed design with random effects for primary and secondary school. $i$ indexes the pupils, $j$ indexes the primary schools and $k$ the secondary schools.

Comment: ...there are always assumptions being made when interpreting something like that, because, again, crossing/nesting is a property of the study design, not the model. so  the authors should explain this at some point.

Comment: Robert, so you're making a distinction between multiple membership designs and crossed designs? It seems to me the former better fits the term `cross-classified` than the latter?  Also, again, in my test items scenario above, do I have $i$, $j$, and $k$ at the same time or not?

Comment: No. Multiple membership is a different thing. That occurs when lower level units, say pupils belong to multiple schools at the same time. A more realistic example is customers who have multiple bank accounts, but again it all depends on the study design. You might not be able to distinguish crossed designs from multiple membership just based on data.. But let's **not** get into multiple membership here. It deserves it's own question !

Comment: Sure thanks! I accepted it.